# Activate function based on URL rather than click

Tags: javascript

I have a toggle function that scrolls the page to a section and opens a tab, based on a click on the left side nav (based the id of the link):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

//Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
$(".toggle_container3").hide();

//Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
$(".trigger3").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
}).first().click()      
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#over_left a").click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr("href");
$(id).addClass("active").next().show("slow");
})
});
</script>
```

Instead of the click being the trigger, I'd like the same loaded URL be the trigger. So, if https://www.sea.edu/sea_research/climate_change#news would also scroll to the News tab and open it (change the class to active) just like the link on the page does. It can be the same tab ID each time - for now only one tab on each page needs to have this treatment.

I don't know what to search for, but something like:

```
 $("URL#news").onload{function()
```

Comment: Does anything other than a pageload cause the url to change? I assume clicks can

Comment: The click is what is causing the URL to change. But I just want to use the same link externally and have the same action as if the user had clicked the link on the loaded page.

Comment: Right. So simply wait for the dom to be ready, check what the hash on the url is currently, then perform an action based on it.

Comment: Well, two actions. Needs to scroll (which it already does) and also change the class on the div to be active, so the tab will open.

Comment: Yes, those actions you already know how to do on click, right? Why would doing it on dom ready be any different?

Comment: I guess it wouldn't but I don't know what code to write wait for the dom to be ready, check the hash, and perform the action. I looked at the link for the answer already given. How do I incorporate `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("[data-load-id='" + window.location.hash + "']")` into the function that changes the class of the tab id?

Comment: You're already waiting for the dom to be ready. `$(document).ready(function(){` *facepalm* Each of those other actions are entirely separate things that are rather easy to research. (the duplicate has an example of each)

Comment: Okay, I hadn't looked at the fiddle yet. I tried `$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = "#news";
 $(this).attr("href");
    $(id).addClass("active").next().show("slow");
 });` but still is just scrolling...

Comment: i mean... you can't use `this` there. or `.attr('href')`. neither make sense in that context. `id` is also not defined.

Comment: Got it working - thanks for your "support." `$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = "#news";
    $("#news").addClass("active").next().show("slow");
 });`

Answer (score -2):

Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/PPGPw/)

Comment: That scrolls the page - but that was already happening with my current javascript. I also need the tab class to change, to active. I tried this: `<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#news').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    $(id).addClass("active").next().show("slow");
 })
});
</script>` on here [https://www.sea.edu/sea_research/test#news] but it still just scrolls